# Report viewer Error message "client found response content type of '' but expected 'text xml' The request failed with an empty response."

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I'm getting the error

```
client found response content type of '' but expected 'text xml' The request failed with an empty response.
```

when I try to execute the following code.

```
//create a PDF from the SQL report
ReportViewer rview = new ReportViewer();

rview.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://server/ReportServer$MSSQL2K5?");

List<ReportParameter> paramList = new List<ReportParameter>();
paramList.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("Batch", "1"));
paramList.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("InvoiceNo", "0"));
rview.ServerReport.ReportPath = "Report/Report Invoice";

rview.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramList);

string mimeType, encoding, extension, deviceInfo;
string[] streamids;
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Warning[] warnings;
string format = "PDF"; //Desired format goes here (PDF, Excel, or Image)             

deviceInfo =
"<DeviceInfo>" +
"<SimplePageHeaders>True</SimplePageHeaders>" +
"</DeviceInfo>";

byte[] bytes = rview.LocalReport.Render(format, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
```

The error occurs on the line:

```
rview.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramList);
```

The address is correct as I can load the report fine via a web browser:

```
this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://server/ReportServer$MSSQL2K5?/Report/Report Invoice&Batch=1&InvoiceNo=0");
```

I need to load the report with the report viewer so I can export as PDF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the Uri to the full service uri, eg:

```
new Uri("http://server/ReportServer$MSSQL2K5/reportservice2005.asmx?")
```

Additionally, do you need the trailing `?`?  I'm not sure, but wouldn't it be appended if needed by `SetParameters`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion which didn't quite work but
   rview.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://devserver/ReportServer$MSSQL2K5/ReportExecution2005.asmx?");

works perfect! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8):

In my case this error was caused by the SSRS server running out of hard drive space.

Answer (score 1):

On my side, the service (SSRS) was hanging on the server side, had to force stop service and restart it.