# Client found response content type of " but expected 'text/xml' The request failed with an empty response

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have consumed the web service in windows application, when pass the request to get response getting an error.

I have used WSE 2.0 to pass the credentials.

```
public string GetResponse(string sPersonnelAreaCode, string sCompanyCode)
{
    try
    {
        WebReference.RIL_STAR_HCM_QueryEmployeeDetails_serviceagent objService1 = new WebReference.RIL_STAR_HCM_QueryEmployeeDetails_serviceagent();
        WebReference.fetchEmployeeListRequestEmployeeList[] objReqs = new WebReference.fetchEmployeeListRequestEmployeeList[1];
        WebReference.fetchEmployeeListRequestEmployeeList objReq1 = new WebReference.fetchEmployeeListRequestEmployeeList();

        WebReference.fetchEmployeeListResponseEmployeeList[] objResponse = new WebReference.fetchEmployeeListResponseEmployeeList[0];
        DataSet dsresult = new DataSet();
        objReq1.PersonnelAreaCode = sPersonnelAreaCode;
        objReq1.CompanyCode = sCompanyCode.ToString();

        UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken("***", "***", PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
        objService1.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(token);
        objReqs[0] = objReq1;
        //In the below line getting that error
        objResponse = objService1.fetchEmployeeList(objReqs);
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Check whether [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33893246/2404470) helps

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the [ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contenttype(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
objReq.ContentType = "text/xml";
```

Assuming you're using `HttpWebRequest`..

Comment: Thanks for your reply...ContentType property is not available in this objReq

Comment: What is the type of `objReq`?

Comment: It clearly isn't - `objReq1.PersonnelAreaCode`. Since when has `string` had a property `PersonnelAreaCode`?

Answer (score 2):

This kind of error usually comes when the report server path is not proper. Double check your `ReportServerUrl`

Also refer [Report viewer Error message "client found response content type of '' but expected 'text xml' The request failed with an empty response."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865825/report-viewer-error-message-client-found-response-content-type-of-but-expect)